# AIR File.resolvePath doesn't work anymore

Tags: flash, air

I'm having a very strange issue, it looks like my application can't create file anymore. It works w/ directories, but the so-many-times-used resolvePath() methods doesn't.
Here is what I do :

```
var databaseFileContent : File = new File(File.desktopDirectory.nativePath + "/testing");
databaseFileContent.createDirectory();
databaseFileContent.resolvePath("test");
```

(Here I'm trying on desktop but that's the same w/ applicationStorageDirectory)

When I execute this, it works only for the "testing" folder which is actually created, but my file isn't. I tried to create another application, doing this :

```
trace(File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("maiswtf.db").exists);
trace(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("wtf.db").exists);
```

Both are displaying "false". Am I missing something here?
I have another application with this code :

```
var databaseFileContent : File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(File.separator + "sitra.db");
```

When I run this one, it works perfectly! My file is created at /sitra.db!

Any hints? I thinks I'm going mad :/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid misunderstood : the file is actually created when opened through a FileStream.